# HashingFunction compatible with Arrays.hashCode

Tags: java, arrays, guava, hashcode

I'm migrating a load of code to stop passing byte[]s, InputStreams and InputSuppliers around and just use ByteSource.

The code currently calculates and ETag for the data by use Arrays.hashCode on the raw byte[], which translates to this with a ByteSource:

```
Arrays.hashCode(dataSource.read());
```

The problem with this is that `dataSource.read()` on a ByteArrayInputSource clones the underlying byte[], which is worse than what's currently there.

I'd like to use `dataSource.hash(HashFunction)` but I want to make sure I don't bust the ETags generated through the hashCode, as this will cause a load of cache invalidations.

Anyone know of a HashFunction that do the job for me?

Comment: Why don't you implement the hash calculation as described in the API documentation of Arrays.hashCode?

Comment: I can, but I'd want to extend AbstractNonStreamingHashFunction which is package scoped, annoyingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any already available `HashFunction` that'll do what you want, but it should be pretty easy to write it yourself. Something like:

```
public final class ByteArrayHashFunction extends AbstractStreamingHashFunction {

  @Override
  public Hasher newHasher() {
    return new ByteArrayHasher();
  }

  @Override
  public int bits() {
    return 32;
  }

  private static final class ByteArrayHasher extends AbstractByteHasher {

    private int hash = 1;

    @Override
    protected void update(byte b) {
      hash = 31 * hash + b;
    }

    @Override
    public HashCode hash() {
      return HashCode.fromInt(hash);
    }
  }
}
```

You would need to copy a few of the abstract classes from `common.hash` into your own package though.

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I ended up with. I actually only need to implement hashBytes() so I just called Arrays.hashCode through that.

Comment: @BenSmith: Assuming you're referring to `AbstractNonStreamingHashFunction`, I would strongly suggest using `AbstractStreamingHashFunction` as I did here. `AbstractNonStreamingHashFunction` (as implied by the "non-streaming" part of the name) doesn't work well for processing a stream of bytes. It's designed for hash functions that have to process a set of bytes all at once, and as such it buffers everything that's written to it until you call `hash()`. The algorithm that `Arrays.hashCode` uses, on the other hand, is very amenable to being used in a streaming manner.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that. Maybe I should go for a Streaming hash function, but as the ByteSource is almost always wrapping a byte array it doesn't matter so much.

Comment: @BenSmith: True, when the `ByteSource` is wrapping a byte array the non-streaming version would even be slightly faster.